# Mutlivariate modelling

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression

I need someone elses perspective on this because I really don't understand what I'm looking at.
I'm supposed to solve this problem:
[image]

The problem is that I don't understand what I'm supposed to model because this data really doesn't make any sense to me. I understand why the dosages are in log scale, and the purpose of the arcsine transformation. But I dont understand the actual "experiment", any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to model the proportion of dead fish with respect to copper dose and the average weight of the fish. So the experiment is probably something like how does copper influence mortality of fish, controlling for their average weight for some reason.

Comment: Sure, but how do I also consider the different time points?

Comment: oh yeah, I missed that. And of course you are supposed to consider different times. They probably won't die immediately. It's probably by using some longitudinal,hierarchical, random effect, or survival model that they are trying to teach you.